# Backup *.pdb files from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, pdb-files

To debug my executable if a customer reports a bug and sents a dump file of it, i backup all *.pdb files created.

I wonder if it's recommanded to store all *.pdb files **or can i skip files created** by visual studio like vc141.pdb (vc142.pdb ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to save all pdb files of the version that run on the production environment that related to your dlls all other pdb you can get from Microsoft.
http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols